# AngularJS better way to read config file?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I built a angularJS app that I wanted dynamically configured, so I created a **config.json**  file with the needed configurations, and decided to load the config file in app.config as such:

```
angular.module("myapp",[]).config([ my injections] , function(my providers){
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xhr.open("GET","config.json"); //my config file
    xhr.send();
    xhr.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200)
        {
            //config file parsed, set up params
        }
    }
})
```

The reason I am doing it this way is because $http is not injected in config state, and I do not want to "configure" the app at a controller level.

The application works fine. it does what I want to do, and everything works great...EXCEPT when it comes to unit testing (with karma + jasmine).

even though in karma.conf i have:

```
{pattern: 'config.json',served:true,watched:false,included:false}
```

defined, when I launch karma, I get a cli [WARN] about config.json 404. and my unit tests to see if everything is configured, fails (i.e it didnt read config.json)

Is there a better way to write config files for unit testing?

Comment: If you are using Gulp or Grunt, you will find [gulp-ng-constant](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-ng-constant)/[grunt-ng-constant](https://github.com/werk85/grunt-ng-constant) useful.

Comment: I am using grunt...but I would like to be able to make it a little bit "dynamic".

my understanding (atleast with how i use grunt) it is more like "during install". kind of procedure

Comment: I'm not sure if Jasmine will allow you to do async api calls out of the box. You may want to try this: https://github.com/derickbailey/jasmine.async

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In our apps we have external file config.js, which contains just ordinary module which provides constants with configuration.

```
angular.module('myAppPrefixconfig')
   .constant('PLAIN_CONSTANT', 'value'),
   .constant('APP_CONFIG', {...});
```

In your app you have dependancy on it, and there is ordinary http request - which can be resolved by your backend with proper configuration.

In Karma tests you can then provide 'testing config' directly in karma.conf.